# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage query takes 28 seconds to load

Tags: mysql, cakephp, schema, innodb, information-schema

I have a Cakephp 3 application running and the mysql Server version: 5.6.32-78.1-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 78.1, Revision 8bb53b6 of MySQL and the performance when querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage` table is really worst.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu 
    INNER JOIN
        information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc 
        ON ( kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA ) 
WHERE
    kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBNAME' 
    AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME' 
    AND rc.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
```

It takes, 28 seconds in average to return 0 rows.

I referred almost all posts but no luck yet. Since the mysql version greater than 5.6, I checked that `innodb_stats_on_metadata` is OFF, please help folks. I would hugely appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

Is this statement generated by Cakephp?  Why?  Can't they find a better way?

`information_schema` is poorly implemented until Version 8.0 (with its Data Dictionary).

How many tables in `DBNAME`?  The more tables, the longer it will take.

If you run the same query a second time, how fast does it run?

There *may* be some settings that are causing this query to be especially slow.  How much RAM do you have?  What are the values from `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`?

Comment: There were not much tables, but I have seen in the Debugkit SQL log that the informationm_schema query is taking 30 seconds to load and is returning 0 rows which means that it doesnt make any difference if I run that query or not since in all the pages the rows were 0. The second time when I was running the query, it was cached and was loading quickly, but after 30 seconds again it was taking time, maybe due to metadata cache and all.u So I removed that query and my application is fast as it should be..

Answer (score 0):

We were using Cake 3.7 against an AWS serverless Aurora/MySQL database. So we were limited on updating the MySQL version. When load testing our application, we were hitting logarithmic scaling issues on the database performance after a certain extent. This was due to those queries piling up. To address this, we simply set 'cacheMetadata' => true, under 'Datasources' in the application configuration.